# Website opens fine on my machine but does not when I host it

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website is mockmydata.com - This website is from a template - it opens fine on my local machine, but when I host it, the pop-ups don't work as expected.

Is it something to do with my "#" tag or is it a javascript that is causing the issue?

Comment: Also a FYI - I have no redirects on thie website yet - and the EXACT set of files works fine from this location: http://mockmydata.com/demo/welcome.html

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a problem with your server.
[403 Error when you try to load the Jquery file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSHcI.png)
You have two solutions :

- Use a CDN

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Or

- Solve your miss configuration on your server, maybe you use a .htaccess that remove the access to your file

Comment: TamirNahum, thanks - but even after removing the htaccess file, I had the issue. So I have simply added a redirect to the "demo" folder where it is working. Will appreciate if you tell me how to get it working from the main folder though.

Comment: And Maxime. Thank you. Using CDN like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your server returns HTML response status 403 for every JavaScript it's trying to load (jQuery for example).
That may be the reason that none of your JavaScript is functioning.